# what's feeding the 'user' in a django template

Tags: django

So I just learn about Class Based View, and how they pass a context to an according template for rendering. But I notice something weird in some code I attach below:

the django template can recognize the `user` in `if user.is_authenticated`, but I check the context of `Sdetailview`, `user` is not in it. And when I log in as admin, the template will render `1`, otherwise render `2`. Does anyone know from where the `user` was passed to the template? what else is passed to template from class based view besides context?

Thank you.

here's the view:

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView
from . import models
class Sdetailview(DetailView):
    context_object_name = "details"
    model = models.School
    template_name = "basicapp/sdetail.html"
```

here's the model template

```
{% extends "basicapp/bbase.html" %}
{% block body_block %}
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<h1>1</h1>
{% else %}
<h1>2</h1>
{% endif %}
<div class="container">
  <h1>School Details</h1>
  <p>{{details.name}}</p>
  <p>{{details.principal}}</p>
  <p>{{details.location}}</p>
    <p><a class='btn btn-warning' href="{% url 'bapp:update' pk=details.pk %}">Update</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DetailView inherits from multiple mixins and attributes as explained [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/).

The context and request are being passed. You could also do

```
request.user.is_authenticated
```

Context processors are being passed as well. 
By default:

```
'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
```

**'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',** is responsible for **user.is_authenticated**

More on context processors [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/api/#built-in-template-context-processors).

Comment: But what get passed to template apart from context?